# Custom styles for bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to change default bootstrap tab styles. So my custom style should be similar to this image's styles.

[image]

I tried it like this, but it's not working. The main thing doesn't skew the bottom of each tabs.

```
.content .nav-tabs {
  background: #dd5b5b;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.content .nav-tabs > li > a {
  padding: 5px 40px;
  background: #eaedf2;
  border: 1px solid #a48686;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 2em;
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5em;
}
```

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/zayijoto/1/edit?html,css) with the code so far

Can anybody help me to get the output like the above image using pure css?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're close but you need to add a gradient, and you can use bootstrap or fort awesome icons for the arrows.  You should potentially use jQuery for the arrows changing color, however if each tab loads a new page then you can just have an `active` class on a single tab for each page.

Comment: @Dan yes it is close and gradient and icons are okay for me. my problem is shape of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap easily allows to customize tabs and their behaviour.

For the colors, consider using Gradients in your CSS, working in the corresponding classes, as you wish. Here is a nice generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

For the icons, you can just use **FontAwesome** (http://fontawesome.io/icons/) or similar webfont.